# Как правильно склонять словосочетание (или слово?) "счет-фактура"?

Tags: склонение

Во-первых, чем нужно считать эту конструкцию: словосочетанием или словом? А в-вторых, никак не могу понять, как правильно ее склонять.
С предложением "для импортного товара требуется счет-фактура" все понятно, но как быть, если нужно написать: "для него требуется предоставление счета-фактуры"? Правильно: "счета-фактуры" или все-таки "счет-фактуры" - ведь этого слово пишется через дефис, а значит, по идее, является цельной конструкцией.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Термин «счёт-фактура» является существительным мужского рода.

Склоняются обе части слова, например, без счёта-фактуры, посмотреть в счёте-фактуре, мн. счета-фактуры, счетов-фактур.

Сложное существительное построено по образцу словосочетания с подчинительной связью  "сущ+приложение", где главным словом является "счет", поэтому сложное слово относится к м.р.

Грамматически это слово ближе к словосочетанию, но в качестве термина рассматривается как сложное слово.

Answer (score 3):

Это сложное существительное мужского рода. Склоняются обе части. Правильно: счёт-фактура, счёта-фактуры, счёту-фактуре, счёт-фактуру, счётом-фактурой, о счёте-фактуре. Множественное число: счета-фактуры.

Answer (score 2):

Во-первых, это одно слово, а не словосочетание. А теперь о склонении. Во-первых, придумаем какакое-нибудь сложное существительное, которое пишется через дефис. Например, при помощи дефиса мы можем обозначить квалификацию, профессию, звание.

Вспомнил одно слово. Член-корреспондент — сложное существительное. В этом слове обе части склоняются. Например, генетивный падеж (или же родительный): Женя нашего члена-корреспондента. Убедиться можно тут: http://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D1%87%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82

Что касается слова, указанное в вопросе, то про него можно посмотреть тут: http://director63.ru/statyi/sklonenie-rod-slova-schet-faktura